# Who is bukhari Sharif?

Tags: sahih-bukhari

Sahih Bukhari is most popular Hadith in Islamic world. We usually find hadith to solve issues related to our religion.

*May Allah forgive me*

I have heard that Bukhari Sharif came after a long time after death of our Prophet Muhammad (SAW) death. Our Prophet were coming to his dreams and telling stories about our Prophet Muhammad (SAW) age.
Some says that an angle were coming usually and telling him stories but I don't really know what is truth.

So my questions stands here, **who was Bukhari sharif, when he was born and how did he write these hadiths?**

Comment: Answer is given and selected but who has vote for closing this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sahih Bukhari was written by a famous Scholar [Muhammad al-Bukhari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_al-Bukhari).

He came at the time of [Abbasid Caliphate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbasid_Caliphate) around 800 AD.

He was born in 810 and died in 870 at the age of 60. He was born in [Bukhara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bukhara), [Khorasan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greater_Khorasan). and he speak Persian. and he was follower of **Imam Shafi**.

And dream are not proper source of hadith for Bukhari. He use to travel the world and collect hadith. If hadith don't have a ravi(full line to who had heard the hadith) the it is zaeef hadith. There is a proper way of explanation to every hadith in **Sahih bukhari** that why it is such a reliable source to hadith.